# error in create array object in java code

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception, arrayobject

i have a class by name card and it's code is bellow

```java
class card {
 private String word, mean;

 public card() {}

 public card(String w, String m) {
  this.word = w;
  this.mean = m;
 }

 // Getter and setter ...

}
```

and then if i write bellow code in main function

```
card[] c=new card[3];   
c[1].setword("Hello");
```

I got `NullPointerException`

how i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you just initialize an array, but not initialized the elements of the array. If you print the elements of the array to System.out, you will see that all of them are null. You have to initialize each element of the array.

```
card[] c = new card[3];
c[1] = new card();
c[1].setword("Hello");
c[2] = new card();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
 card[] c=new card[3];
```

you just created an array object with size = 3 to store `card` but didn't create any `card` object.
So to fix it, you have to create `card` object and store in your array.

```java
card[] cards = new card[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   cards[i] = new card();
}
cards[1].setword("Hello");
```

By the way, you should name your class with the first letter is upper case, it's java naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the object first then set the value like below -

```
c[1] = new card();
```

then

```
c[1].setword("Hello");
```

Hope this will help.